# How to group data and get and get all the field back in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have collection in a mongodb and want to group invoice by modified and get all the fields in those objects.

```
{ 
   modified: "11/02/2020",
   stocks: [
             {
              product:{
                 name:"Milk",
                 price: 20
              }
              quantity: 2,
              paid: true
            }
          ]
},
{ 
  modified: "10/02/2020",
  stocks: [
             {
              product:{
                 name:"Sugar",
                 price: 50
              }
              quantity: 1,
              paid: false
            }
   ]
 },
 { 
   modified: "10/02/2020",
   stocks: [
             {
              product:{
                       name:"Butter",
                       price: 10
                    }
              quantity: 5,
              paid: false
            }
        ]
   }
```

So I tried:

```
  db.collection.aggregate([{
        $group: {
          _id: "$modified",  
          records: { $push: "$$ROOT" } 
        }
     }
  ])
```

But It reaggregate on the modifier field being pushed into the records generating duplicates

Comment: add your sample data https://mongoplayground.net/ and query

Comment: Thanks, but how to do the query is what am actually asking for

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/4AGuo5zfF4V

Use [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: { _id: "$grade",  records: { $push: "$$ROOT" } }
  }
])
```

---

Output

```
[
  {
    "_id": "A",
    "records": [
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
        "grade": "A",
        "name": "John",
        "subject": "English"
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
        "grade": "A",
        "name": "John1",
        "subject": "English"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "B",
    "records": [
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002"),
        "grade": "B",
        "name": "JohnB",
        "subject": "English"
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000003"),
        "grade": "B",
        "name": "JohnB1",
        "subject": "English"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: It works with the previous data but when I ran it again with above data set it re-run the aggregation loop on the modified field within the records resulting to duplicates

Comment: @yaxx What do you mean duplicates?

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/ymUeh9gArSv ??

Comment: _id must be included. Otherwise, it will throw an error.